# Kubuntu - missing menu bar at the top, and task bar at the bottom

Tags: kubuntu

I have pressed something, and top menu bar and task bar at the bottom of the KUbuntu screen, has disappeared, it looks like some fullscreen mode or something got turned on.

Any ideas how to switch back?

Answer (score 2):

Following helped:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
gnome-panel
```